# Jenkins webhook triggered pipeline job but status unchanged

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks

I have a pipeline that I want to run e2e test after deploying to uat environment, the e2e test runs on gitlab. What I want to do is to let gitlab use webhook to trigger jenkins to decide if the build could go to production or not. So the pipline looks as below.

[image]

After deploying to uat, I can send the webhook to trigger e2e test on gitlab. And gitlab can send the webhook to jenkins, however, as the pipeline job e2e received the webhook and build success. It does not change the pipeline job status, and hence, we can not proceed to deploy to production unless we manually click the trigger on e2e job. And I already try to use `currentBuild.currentResult` and `currentBuild.result` which doesn't seem to work.

What should I do to solve this?

**Update**

I am not using the new pipeline way with groovy, instead, I'm doing it the old way like this. But I supposed this is not related to the issue I'm trying to solve here.

[image]

Let me provide more details about the problem. After e2e test is done, I send below request from gitlab to jenkins

`curl "SERVER_URL/job/MY_XXX_PROJECT/view/Pipeline/job/X.X%20E2E%20my_e2e_test_result/buildWithParameters?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&PARENT_BUILD_NUMBER=123&currentBuild.currentResult=SUCCESS&currentBuild.Result=SUCCESS"`

And here is the pipeline, and if I check the job in `SERVER_URL/job/MY_XXX_PROJECT/view/Pipeline/job/X.X%20E2E%20my_e2e_test_result/`. The job is actually built **SUCCESS**.

[image: pipeline status]

However, the status shows like nothing happened, and we cannot proceed to deploy production without manually clicking the trigger button on the same job(e2e) again.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Gitlab should call the Jenkins webhook to fire up the e2e job, but it's Jenkins that decides what the status of the build is. Are you simply looking for a way for the Jenkins job to update its own status? If so, Are you using scripted or declarative pipelines?

Comment: In the last build steps of jenkins UAT, I send a post request to gitlab to run e2e test. After the e2e test is done, gitlab send webhook to jenkins to notify the test result which is either success or fail. However, as jenkins received webhook and run the job, it does not update the status of the job. I want jenkins to update status of the job to success or fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a way for the job to update its own state, use the `unstable` and the `error` steps.

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
            echo 'This job is now a success. All jobs are a success until marked otherwise'.
            //success 'This will fail. There's no such thing as a success step'
            unstable 'This stage is now unstable'
            error 'This job is now failed'
            unstable 'This job is still failed. Build results can only get worse. They can never be improved.'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Notice that there's no such thing as a `success` step. Probably because **all jobs are a success until told otherwise**. And the overall result of a job **cannot be improved**. See the documentation for `catchError` [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure).

> Note that the build result can only get worse, so you cannot change the result to SUCCESS if the current result is UNSTABLE or worse.

Comment: I just provide more details in the question. thanks for your help, but I'm still stucking here